# Replacing a number in random.randint with a letter python

Tags: python

```
import random

for i in range(1):

    myNum= str(random.randint(1,5))

    print(myNum)
```

Wanted to replace every occurrence of the number 1 with the letter j in python, how would one go about doing this?

Comment: Use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to just select from the options you want in the first place:

```
myNum = random.choice(('j', '2', '3', '4', '5'))

# Equivalently, assuming they're all one character values:
myNum = random.choice('j2345')
```

Might even run a touch faster, since there are no type conversions needed (and a `tuple` of literal constants is cached in the function/module constants at least on CPython, so it won't be reconstructed over and over).

Comment: Sorry, I meant, how can you create a counter that displays the amount of times that the random.choice doesn't select the letter j

Comment: @user7486559: This is starting to sound a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). If you only care about the number of times `j` comes up, you don't need `j` at all, you could just increment a counter 20% of the time. Incrementing a counter is trivial, and if you don't understand that much, you really need to take some programming classes, you're not going to learn well asking trivial questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

So long as it is just a single character from a string length up to 9, you can do:

```
my_chr='j2345'[random.randint(0,4)]
```

Just make sure that the string is the same length as the potential range of the random int.

Comment: Umm, that will never select `j`, and get an IndexError 20% of the time. The `random.choice` option in my answer bypasses the risks of getting your bounds wrong, while being otherwise equivalent.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Just use an if statement:

```
     import random

     for i in range(1):
          myNum = random.randint(1, 5)
          if myNum == 1:
              print("j")
```

Comment: `for i in range(1):` does nothing useful

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: The OP did it too though. Might want to bring it up in a comment on the question.

Comment: That is true, it should be more like this: for i in range(10):